# How to force Gnome's WM (metacity) to open a program window on a specific monitor?

Tags: xorg, gnome, window-manager, multi-monitor

I need to configure a dual-head machine using Debian 6 (and, hence, Gnome 2.30.2 and xrandr 1.3.3) so that it opens applications reliably on a certain screen.

While it is trivial to move normal windows from one monitor to the other by just dragging their title bars, we need to run Stellarium, which opens an undecorated  fullscreen window that doesn't even respond to ALT-dragging it. It also does not seem to use the standard X command line switches -geometry, -display and so on.

Since this is a machine that will be shared by many users, I am especially interested in simple, intuitive and documentable solutions.

Answer (score 4):

[Devil's Pie](http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie) probably does the job, it

> can be configured to detect windows as they are created, and match the window to a set of rules. If the window matches the rules, it can perform a series of actions on that window.

The last news entry there is 5 years old, but it's probably ok (based on [EWMH, Extended Window Manager Hints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EWMH)).

(Regarding automated window things using X11, there is also [`wmctrl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl), but I doubt it is of any use here.)

Comment: Aha! I have indeed used wmctrl for a couple of years in a shell script that I invoke from Alt-F2 after my Gnome session is all started. Instead of looking for a way to trigger that automatically when the session is fully started, I can try Devil's Pie.

Answer (score 1):

You can also launch Stellarium in window mode with a command-line option:

```
stellarium --full-screen no
```

See Stellarium's man page for details.

You can also set the full-screen flag in Stellarium's configuration file, as well as the starting size of the window.